# Logic Gates and Circuits - What is the self in Connector class stand for

Tags: class, python-3.x, object

I am learning about object oriented programming from

Problem solving with Algorithms and Data structures book.

I have trouble understanding the setNextPin(self,source) method in Connector Class. I understand that the tgate.setNextPin(self) mean tgate.setNextPin(tgate,self) but what really is self here ?? It is confusing with me what the self of Connector stand for ??
Logically, this method will set tgate.PinA = self, and becaause we want tgate to take value from fgate so self == fgate ? Sorry if the question is stupid or confusing

```
class Connector:

    def __init__(self, fgate, tgate):
        self.fromgate = fgate
        self.togate = tgate

        tgate.setNextPin(self)

    def getFrom(self):
        return self.fromgate

    def getTo(self):
        return self.togate
```

I think I understand the basic idea of self, but if we have:

```
g1 = AndGate("G1") 
g2 = AndGate("G2") 
g3 = OrGate("G3") 
c1 = Connector(g1,g3)
```

So in this case which is g3.setNexPin(self) will set the next pin of g3 to c1 ?? but c1 is only a connector and donot hold any value ??

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the purpose of self in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

Comment: Yes, `g3.setNextPin(self)`  would set "next" pin of `g3` to `c1`. As for the next sentence, could you please elaborate what do you mean by "but c1 is only a connector and donot hold any value ??", as I am not familiar with this book.

Comment: ah sorry, I mean the pin of g3 must be a value right. g3 is a OrGate class which take two value, for example False or False and return the value False. What I means is c1 do not hold any value so how can we set pin of g3 to c1

Comment: @AnhHoang Be careful to keep straight the difference between the variables `g3` and `c1` in your Python code and the behavior of the objects to which they refer.

Comment: From what you have shown here, no Boolean values are stored anywhere. However, you haven't posted any code for your gate classes. It is probably easiest to think of the `Connector` class as representing the wire which connects the pins for the gates on a breadboard.

Comment: ah, I finally understand the logic here, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`self` refers to the "current" object. In `__init__()` this is the object which is being created and initialized. So `tgate.setNextPin(self)` sets the next pin of `tgate` to the current `Connector`. It is not `fgate` as you guessed. It is the new `Connector` which is being initialized.

For more details, see [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/what-is-the-purpose-of-self-in-python)

> So in this case which is `g3.setNexPin(self)` will set the next pin of g3 to c1 ??

That is basically correct. A small nitpick: The actual code is `tgate.setNextPin(self)`. In this particular case, `tgate` refers to the same object as `g3` and `self` refers to the object that is being created. After `__init__()` returns, `c1` will be assigned to refer to this newly created object.

Comment: I think I understand the basic idea, but if we have: 
g1 = AndGate("G1") 
g2 = AndGate("G2")
g3 = OrGate("G3")
c1 = Connector(g1,g3)
so in this case which is g3.setNexPin(self) will set the next pin of g3 to c1 ?? but c1 is only a  connector and donot hold any value ??

Comment: @AnhHoang You should consider editing your question if you have further details...especially code since you cannot format well it in a comment.

Comment: I have edited the question to be more clear, please help

Comment: here is the link to the chapter with full code at the end http://interactivepython.org/runestone/static/pythonds/Introduction/ObjectOrientedProgramminginPythonDefiningClasses.html

Answer (score 1):

I just stumbled on this question reading this book. I found the answer when I tried to
execute the entire active code given at the end of the section. In the BinaryGate Class, the `getPinA()` returns

```
'self.pinA.getFrom().getOutput()'
```

So breaking down -

```
'self.pinA --> c1' 
'c1.getFrom() --> g1'
'g1.getOutput() --> gets the output of gate g1'
```

This `getPinA()` is used to send the input to the binary gate and thus it makes sense to provide the connector as the source to `tgate.setNextPin()`

link for reference: https://runestone.academy/runestone/books/published/pythonds/Introduction/